# T-SQL - Add Quote to html attribute value

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, function, quote

Today I've problem with t-sql function to replace html attribute tag, when attribute value does not a quote (cellpadding=1, border=1. cellspacing =1, rowspan=2 etc.). 
I can't use REPLACE function, because value of all attribute in example is dynamic (sometimes is 1, 2, 3 2, 3).

Html parse to xml and when attribute value is not in quote then have a error.

Do you have any example or idea how to create function in t-sql ?

Best regards
Jakub

Comment: This is not something TSQL does well. A better option may be to fetch the data to an application and do the processing there.

Comment: I getting html from company and in table has invalid attribute value. Can create in application but i'm creating SSIS package. Is required...

Comment: Joachim,thanks. In ssis i created a script task and remove html attrbutes without quote via Regex ;).

Comment: @JakubKlekota I suggest posting that you solved it that way as an answer and accept it - that way when people like me who come looking for unanswered questions can see that it is resolved (and how!) without digging through the comments.